# How to fill up DataGrid based on XML in WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datagrid

i have the following XML and i would like to fill up a DataGrid in WPF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Start>
<General>
<ItemList>
  <Item>
    <name>iustin</name>
    <value>20</value>
    <behaviourList>
      <behaviour>1</behaviour>
      <behaviour>2</behaviour>
      <behaviour>3</behaviour>
      <behaviour>4</behaviour>
    </behaviourList>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <name>alin</name>
    <value>30</value>
    <behaviourList>
      <behaviour>1</behaviour>
      <behaviour>2</behaviour>
      <behaviour>3</behaviour>
      <behaviour>4</behaviour>
    </behaviourList>
      </Item>
    </ItemList>
  </General>
</Start>
```

i have done this.

```
public MainWindow()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
           DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
           dataSet.ReadXml(@"C:\Users\WAVI\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\DummyProject\DummyProject\XML\TemperatureSensors.xml");

        dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables[2].DefaultView;
    }
```

but i cant get the behaviourList to be displayed and i know its because i said: Tables[2] and this is Tables[3] but i can't figure it out how to solve this. Also i would like the behaviours to be a ComboBox.

P.S: this is just an example, but the idea is the make it in a generic way.

Thank you

Comment: You probably have to parse the file yourself and not use a DataSet,  The xml is calling the DataSet the 1st tag "Start".  Then creating a table "General".  The next level tag(s) are the column names.  And finally the row data.  You have more levels of tags which is causing issue.  The ReadXml starts parsing data into more tables which make it hard to work with the final results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Behaviour", typeof(int));

            foreach(XElement item in doc.Descendants("Item"))
            {
                string name = (string)item.Element("name");
                int value = (int)item.Element("value");
                foreach (XElement behaviour in item.Descendants("behaviour"))
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { name, value, (int)behaviour });
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```